# Как исключить из выборки sql запроса дубли-перевертыши?

Tags: sql, mysqli

Есть `table1 (is, surename)`, `table2(id, reporter,assign)`

`reporter` и `assign` у table2 ссылаются на `Id` в table1. В результате нужно сделать выборку всех записей table2, исключая дубли перевертыши, к примеру `reporter=2`, `assigne=1` не должно дублироваться как `assigne=2`, `reporter=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понимаю, зачем в задаче `table1`, если задание:

> В результате нужно сделать выборку всех записей table2

Которое можно сделать запросом:

```
select distinct t1.*
from test t1
where not exists
          (select *
           from test t2
           where t2.reporter = t1.assign
                 and t2.assign = t1.reporter
                 and t2.reporter > t1.reporter
                 and t2.assign < t1.assign)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba29ad/3)

Answer (score -1):

Если нужны только уникальные комбинации, то можно поступить так:

```
select distinct case when reporter > assign then assign else reporter end, 
case when reporter > assign then reporter else assign end
from table2
```